# Should the PARSE dialect be used on tasks that are fundamentally about modifying the input?

Tags: json, parsing, rebol, dialect

In honor of Rebol 3 going open source [any-minute-now (?)](http://www.rebol.com/cgi-bin/blog.r?view=0516), I'm back to messing with it.  As an exercise I'm trying to write my own JSON parser in the PARSE dialect.

Since Douglas Crockford [credits influence of Rebol on his discovery of JSON](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=780554), I thought it would be easy.  Outside of replacing braces with brackets and getting rid of all those commas, one of the barriers to merely using `LOAD` on the string is the fact that when they want to do the equivalent of a `SET-WORD!` they use something that looks like a string to Rebol's tokenizer, with an illegal stray colon after it:

```
{
    "key one": {
         "summary": "This is the string content for key one's summary",
         "value": 7
    },
    "key two": {
         "summary": "Another actually string, not supposed to be a 'symbol'",
         "value": 100
    }
}
```

Basically I wanted to find all the cases that were like `"foo bar":` and turn them into `foo-bar:` while leaving matching quote pairs that were not followed by colons alone.

When I tackled this in PARSE (which I understand rather well in principle but still haven't used much) a couple of questions came up.  But mainly, what are the promised conditions under which when you can escape into code and modify the series out from under the parser...specifically in Rebol 3?  More generally, is it the *"right kind of tool for the job"*?

Here was the rule I tried, that appears to work for this part of the task:

```
any [
    ; require a matched pair of quotes & capture series positions before
    ; and after the first quote, and before the last quote

    to {"} beforePos: skip startPos: to {"} endPos: skip

    ; optional colon next (if not there the rest of the next rule is skipped)

    opt [
        {:}

        ; if we got to this part of the optional match rule, there was a colon.
        ; we escape to code changing spaces to dashes in the range we captured

        (
            setWordString: copy/part startPos endPos
            replace/all setWordString space "-"
            change startPos setWordString
        )

        ; break back out into the parse dialect, and instead of changing the 
        ; series length out from under the parser we jump it back to the position
        ; before that first quote that we saw

        :beforePos

        ; Now do the removals through a match rule.  We know they are there and
        ; this will not cause this "colon-case" match rule to fail...because we
        ; saw those two quotes on the first time through!

        remove [{"}] to {"} remove [{"}]
    ]
]
```

Is that okay?  Is there any chance of the `change startPos setWordString` in the open code mucking up the outer parse...if not in this case, then in something subtly different?

As always, any didactic *"it's cleaner/shorter/better this other way"* advice is appreciated.

**P.S.** why isn't there a `replace/all/part`?

Comment: This is not what you've asked, but check this great piece of code if you did not already: http://reb4.me/r/altjson REBOL<->JSON converter from Christopher Ross-Gill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new keywords like `change`, `insert` and `remove` should facilitate this type of thing. I guess the main downside to this approach is the latency issues in pushing series around (I've seen mention that it is faster to build new strings than to manipulate).

```
token: [
    and [{"} thru {"} any " " ":"]
    remove {"} copy key to {"} remove {"} remove any " "
    (key: replace/all key " " "-")
]

parse/all json [
    any [
        to {"} [
            and change token key
            ; next rule here, example:
            copy new-key thru ":" (probe new-key)
            | skip
        ]
    ]
]
```

This is a bit convoluted as I can't seem to get 'change to work as I'd expect (behaves like `change`, not `change/part`), but in theory you should be able to make it shorter along these lines *and* have a fairly clean rule. Ideal might be:

```
token: [
    {"} copy key to {"} skip any " " and ":"
    (key: replace/all key " " "-")
]

parse/all json [
    any [
        to {"} change token key
        | thru {"}
    ]
]
```

Edit: Another fudge around `change` -

```
token: [
    and [{"} key: to {"} key.: skip any " " ":"]
    (key: replace/all copy/part key key. " " "-")
    remove to ":" insert key
]

parse/all json [
    any [to {"} [token | skip]]
]
```

Comment: +1 This answers some of the "is it possible" part. The potential slowness is a good point as well. Though I'm still wondering about the limits of legality in terms of your contract with PARSE. The easiest contract would be *"don't change the input out from under the parser"*, but if your input is nested blocks instead of strings aliasing may make that hard to promise. Also: I added a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152002/why-do-unknown-language-ids-in-prettification-fall-back-to-guessing-instead-of) about the syntax highlighting edit I made to your post...

Comment: I don't see a problem with changing the input, per se, I guess the trouble would be if you expected the value to be unchanged at some other point. Kind of like doing – `key: "Key" print uppercase key` – without realising you've altered the string `'key` points to. I suppose it depends how clever you want to be. The philosophy behind `'and` imo lends to a more responsible approach to doing multi-pass parsing, especially if the first pass does modify the source. Anyway, still not sure if I'm grasping the essence of your question, would like to :)

Comment: Agreed on syntax – if it doesn't recognise lang-rebol, best not to colour at all.

Comment: "I'm still wondering about the limits of legality in terms of your contract with PARSE." - do not worry about the "legality in terms of your contract with PARSE". However, do worry about the slowness and never modify input if you do want elementary PARSE operations to remain elementary in terms of speed. (I hope you know that ignoring such speed hogs is not clever)

Comment: Note that there is nothing about PARSE in specific that makes the modifying operations slow. Even their regular function counterparts are slow in the same circumstances. You can't avoid the slowdown by not using PARSE, and just using the REMOVE function instead, for instance. Also, PARSE's CHANGE operation acts like CHANGE/part - the /part is the span that is matched by its first argument rule.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to think about parse as a compiler-compiler with EBNF. If I recall the R2 syntax correctly:

```
copy token [rule] (append output token)
```

Assuming correct syntax, and no `{"}` in strings:

```
thru {"} skip copy key to {"} skip
; we know ":" must be there, no check
thru {"} copy content to {"} skip
(append output rejoin[ {"} your-magic-with key {":"} content {"} ])
```

More precise, instead of `to`, char by char:

```
any space  {"} copy key some [ string-char | "\" skip ] {"} 
any space ":" any space {"} copy content any [ string-char  | "\" skip ] {"} 
(append output rejoin[ {"} your-magic-with key {":"} content {"} ])
; content can be empty -> any, key not -> some
```

`string-char` would be a charset with anything except `{\}` and `{"}`, syntax?

Don't know if R3 still works like this... :-/

Comment: PARSE is not compatible with EBNF. Instead, it is compatible with the TDPL language family (which includes TDPL, GTDPL and PEG).

Answer (score 0):

Since others have answered the `parse` question, I'll answer the P.S.:

There are a few proposed options that have never been added to `replace`, and the main reason is that processing options has overhead, and this function has already needed some interesting optimizations to even handle the options it already has. We were going to try to replace the function with a native once we improved its API a little. It's basically a similar situation to the `reword` function, where we didn't decide on a final API until recently. For `replace` we haven't even had that discussion yet.

In the case of the `/part` option, it simply hasn't been suggested by anyone before, and might be a little conceptually awkward to unify with the existing internal length calculations. It would be possible to have a limited `/part` option, just the integer instead of the offset reference. It would probably be best if the `/part` length took priority over the internally calculated length. Still, if we end up going with an adjusted API there might be no need for a `/part` option.